# Search Property for Sites

Tags: search, permissions

I know there is a way to search so that the results are only sites.

Eg. Type: Site
^ Doesn't work

Does anyone know what the property is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
{sitename} contentclass:STS_Web
```

where {sitename} is the text based on which you want to search the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new search scope and add a rule for `Content Class = "STS_Web"`
Then make sure to require that this condition is met.

See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/define-scopes-for-searches-HA010241119.aspx) for step-by-step instructions to add a new search scope.